# Swift range of substring - search string with wildcard

Tags: search, swift3, nsstring, substring, wildcard

Is it possible to search string within another string using wildcards ?
I want to find occurrence of  ""text1" = "text2"" where text1 and text2 can be any string.

My initial string is

"This is my string. This string includes "text1" = "text2" and much more"

I don't know text1 and text2 when searching.
I thought about something like ""*" = "*"" but no results.

EDIT:
Let my try to explain on other example.
I have *.swift file with a couple occurrences of locX extension

```
        labelPatternForExpresion.stringValue = "labelPatternForExpresion".locX(withComment: "comment one")
    labelPath.stringValue = "labelPathToProject".locX(withComment: "comment six")
    labelHeader.stringValue = "labelFileHeader".locX(withComment: "no comment")
    btnFromFile.title = "btnFromFile".locX(withComment: "empty comment")
    btnCancel.title = "btnCancel".locX(withComment: "")
```

I need to iterate through the file and find all pairs key-comment:

"labelPatternForExpresion" - "comment one"

"labelPathToProject" - "comment six"

........

........

"btnCancel" - ""

Comment: Most likely swift can use regular expressions like many other current programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your pattern is:

```
"textA" - "textB"
```

and you want to capture `textA` and `textB`. Use `NSRegularExpression`:

```
let str = "\"labelPatternForExpresion\" - \"comment one\""

// NSRegularExpression still deals in NSString so let's make a copy to 
// lessen the pain later
let nsStr = str as NSString
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\"(.+)\" - \"(.+)\"", options: [])

if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsStr.length)) {
    let lhs = nsStr.substring(with: match.rangeAt(1))
    let rhs = nsStr.substring(with: match.rangeAt(2))
    print(lhs)
    print(rhs)
}
```